# Can I have a "singleton" emacs instance?

Tags: emacs

In other words, can I start emacs once, and whenever I type emacs whatever in terminal, have it open as a buffer in my existing emacs instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

How you do it depends on the OS and version of emacs (XEmacs, GNU emacs) you are running.  A  good place to start is to look at [GnuClient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuClient) and [EmacsClient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient).

Answer (score 5):

[rant]This yet another of those features that is a no-brainer and enabled by default on many other editors, but proves to be quite difficult in Emacs.[/rant]

Anyway, here's how I have done it. First, as jwernerny mentioned, [EmacsClient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) does the trick. All you have to do to edit foo.txt is

```
emacsclient --alternate-editor='' foo.txt
```

This command will try to connect to a running Emacs server. If there is no server, it will start one. It will then connect to the server and instruct it to open the specified file.

The server runs as a daemon (background process). If you run `ps x | grep emacs` you'll see a process with the command-line `emacs --daemon`. The problem I had was that Emacs only runs in a terminal if you do it like this, so if you want to run it in a graphical window, read on... (and kill that daemon process first)

Here's what I have added to my .bashrc:

```
alias e='emacsclient --no-wait --alternate-editor ~/.emacs.d/start.sh'
```

and the contents of `~/.emacs.d/start.sh` are:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs --eval '(server-start)' $* &
```

The `e` alias can then be used to open a file, either by starting a fresh Emacs instance (with a server), or using an existing one.

For an editor command that waits until you're finished with the file (good for Git commits etc), remove the `--no-wait` option. I do this in my .bashrc:

```
export EDITOR='emacsclient --alternate-editor ~/.emacs.d/start.sh'
```

Use `C-x #` when you're done editing the file. Good old `C-x k` will ask the annoying question "Buffer foo.txt still has clients; kill it?"

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I have an e.bat on Windows, and now I also have it on Linux.